# Solve the following boundary value problems

Tags: partial-differential-equations

$$ \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial x \partial y}  (x,y) =3x^{2}  , u(x,0) = x^n (n > 0) , u(0,y) = 0 $$

---

This is what I've done so far...

$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} (x,y) = x^3 + f(y) $$

Integrate respect to $y$

$$ u(x,y) = x^{3} y + F(y) + g(x) ; \frac{\partial}{\partial y} F(y) = f(y) $$

$$ u(x,0) = x^n \implies x^{3} \cdot 0 + F(0) + g(x) = x^{n} \implies F(0) + g(x) = x^n$$

$$ u(0,y) = 0 \implies 0 \cdot y + F(y) + g(0) = 0 \implies F(y) + g(0) = 0$$

$$ u(x,y) = x^3y - g(0) + x^n - F(0)  $$

$$ u(0,y) = 0 \implies 0 - g(0) + 0 -F(0) = 0 \implies g(0) = - F(0) $$

so.., 
$$ u(x,y) = x^3y + x^n $$

is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is correct. You can check by plugging the solution into the equation. You easily check that when $y = 0$, $x^3 y + x^n = x^n$. And similarly when $x = 0$, $x^3y + x^n = 0$, so the boundary conditions check out. Then taking the appropriate derivatives you have that

$$ \partial^2_{xy} (x^3 y + x^n) = 3x^2 $$

as desired. So you've found a solution to the boundary value problem.

Incidentally, by appealing to the fundamental theorem of calculus, we can conclude from your solution method that the solution is in fact unique.